# How do I do a case-insensitive mod_rewrite redirect to the same URL (mod case)?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm using a case-sensitive web application to serve a few URLs that will be printed, so we expect UsErs to type them with inexact case. How do I tell `mod_rewrite` to redirect to the correct case URL as in `[NC]` without also redirecting on the case-exact URL and creating a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on a few things in your web application, but you could:

1. Use mod_speling to force the correct capitalization of filenames and directories. This requires "real" filenames.
2. Use RewriteMap to rewrite the url ([as seen here](http://blog.dreamhosters.com/kbase/index.cgi?area=1153)):

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteMap insensitive tolower:
RewriteRule ^[\/]*(.*)$ /${insensitive:$1} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you can use mod_speling that's easiest, but that requires actual files, not stuff hiding inside an application somehow.

Simply set a condition so the rewriterule doesn't happen if the request is capitalized properly, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Your/File$
RewriteRule ^/your/file$ /Your/File [NC,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mount a Samba share to /var/www
and consider the Samba-share folder your wwwroot ;-))